# Which are all of the Class Mods in Borderlands 2 that provide team benefits?

Tags: borderlands-2

I was wondering what all the class mods that provide team benefits are in Borderlands 2, and couldn't find a single place listing all of them at once. What is a comprehensive list of all the class mods that provide "Team ________" in Borderlands 2?

Answer (score 1):

Based on all the [class mods listed on Lootlemon](https://www.lootlemon.com/db/borderlands-2/class-mods):

| Vault Hunter | Class Mod | Team Effects |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Axton | [Legendary Ranger](https://www.lootlemon.com/class-mod/legendary-ranger-bl2) | Shield Recharge Rate, Shield Recharge Delay |
| Axton | [Tactician](https://www.lootlemon.com/class-mod/tactician-axton-bl2) | Shield Recharge Rate, Shield Recharge Delay |
| Axton | [Gunner](https://www.lootlemon.com/class-mod/gunner-axton-bl2) | Fire Rate |
| Gaige | [Legendary Catalyst](https://www.lootlemon.com/class-mod/legendary-catalyst-bl2) | Elemental Effect Damage |
| Gaige | [Catalyst](https://www.lootlemon.com/class-mod/catalyst-gaige-bl2) | Elemental Effect Damage |
| Gaige | [Sweetheart](https://www.lootlemon.com/class-mod/sweetheart-gaige-bl2) | Max Health |
| Krieg | [Legendary Reaper](https://www.lootlemon.com/class-mod/legendary-reaper-bl2) | Kill Skill Duration |
| Krieg | [Reaper](https://www.lootlemon.com/class-mod/reaper-krieg-bl2) | Kill Skill Duration |
| Maya | [Legendary Nurse](https://www.lootlemon.com/class-mod/legendary-nurse-bl2) | Health Regen |
| Maya | [Legendary Binder](https://www.lootlemon.com/class-mod/legendary-binder-bl2) | Cooldown Rate |
| Maya | [Binder](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Binder)* | Cooldown Rate |
| Salvador | [Legendary Hoarder](https://www.lootlemon.com/class-mod/legendary-hoarder-bl2) | Ammo Regen |
| Salvador | [Hoarder](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Hoarder)* | Ammo Regen |
| Salvador | [Devastator](https://www.lootlemon.com/class-mod/devastator-salvador-bl2) | Mag Size |
| Zer0 | [Legendary Killer](https://www.lootlemon.com/class-mod/legendary-killer-bl2) | Crit Damage |
| Zer0 | [Killer](https://www.lootlemon.com/class-mod/killer-zer0-bl2) | Crit Damage |
| Zer0 | [Shot](https://www.lootlemon.com/class-mod/shot-zer0-bl2) | Accuracy |

*not listed on Lootlemon, found on https://borderlands.fandom.com